# Cracking RSA without private key

Tags: rsa

I was wondering whether RSA can be cracked given:

- The public key
- A plaintext of a known cipher text.
  In other words the decrypted message from an encrypted one (but without knowing the private key)
  I.E.: you have managed to find the plaintext of an already encrypted message using the public key, however, you DO NOT know the private key.

Comment: You may try here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you have a super computer you can try to factor the private key from public key using some good super polinomial algorithms

Comment: In asymmetric encryption (RSA) encryption is done using the public key so any user can generate a valid plain/cipher text combo using the public key. Asymmetric schemes would be completely pointless if users were to be able to decrypt having just this combo and public key. Encryption schemes which allow users to generate valid cipher text from plain text and are still secure are "chosen cipher text" secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's called a known-plaintext attack, and there is no such attack known against RSA.

Comment: though pretty much everything is said I'm wondering about the special circumstances. Because I know we discussed a stuff like that in our cryptography course. For example something like the key is from a special type. However that's not fitting the requirements asked but still interesting to think about. Maybe ask http://mathoverflow.net/ as well!